# Will linking to a lot of favicon image sizes make the page slower?

Tags: html, css, favicon, load-time

From this gist: https://gist.github.com/awesome/9947977, there are many options for adding the favicon graphic. Will many references to the  tag slow down the page? Or is this just a bad idea?

Comment: I suggest you try it out: take a look at your browser's request history (F12 in IE, Chrome, Firefox) and seeing if it makes any unnecessary requests for irrelevant favicons.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, but not that much.**

[Chrome and Firefox tend to load all PNG icons](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#troubleshootings) the first time they encounter the declaration, thus the "Yes". Subsequent browsing does not generate additional, unnecessary requests, thus the "not that much".

Also, I don't totally agree with the code you link to. In particular, all iOS PNG icons (such as `favicon-57x57.png`) are duplicated and won't be used (eclipsed by `apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png` in this example). But Chrome and FF will load them for no reason.

I rather advice you to use this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). The generated pictures and code support all major platforms and minimize overhead. Well, this is a matter of balance. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: That's the real favicon generator for sure !

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink will not make the page load slower.  if you want to display all of the icons on the page it will hardly effect the performance because of the low resolution.